# How to use JavaScript variable within innerhtml of an html tag (create a list item with variable name)

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I tried

```
let somejsvar = 'hello world'
document.getElementById('id_element_in_html').innerHTML = '<li> somejsvar </li>';
```

My output:

```
>>> - somejsvar
```

Desired output:

```
>>> - hello world
```

Comment: Use string interpolation with es6 `.innerHTML = \`<li>${somejsvar}</li>\``

Comment: Basic string concatenation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change somejsvar from hard coded to the variable itself by adding ${ Your Variable} and use `   to wrap the whole string

```
document.getElementById('id_element_in_html').innerHTML = `<li> ${somejsvar}</li>`;
```

Comment: That is wrong. String interpolation in js is with `${myvar}`

Comment: Read more about ES6 Template string: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: Always used php string interpolation but never knew that was also possible in JS. damn

Answer (score 1):

you need to break out of html

```
document.getElementById('id_element_in_html').innerHTML = '<li>' + somejsvar + ' </li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate variable value

```
let somejsvar = 'hello world'
document.getElementById('id_element_in_html').innerHTML = '<li>' + somejsvar + '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to set the value of innerHTML to plain text `'<li>  somejsvar </li>'`.

Instead you should use JS Concatenation:

```
document.getElementById('id_element_in_html').innerHTML = '<li> ' + somejsvar + ' </li>';
```